# Java Builder version 9 not supported

Tags: java, marklogic, marklogic-9

I'm somewhat new to Java. I'm getting the error below when trying to build my project.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
    Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'spring-data-marklogic'.
    Version '9' not supported
```

From what I can tell it wants me to use Java 8. I've went into Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite) preferences and changed the JRE and JDK to be 8.
I've edited JAVA_HOME to also point to version 8.
However, 'java -version' tells me that I'm still using 9. Regardless, I would think that at least changing the Preferences in my IDE would fix it.

This makes me believe that maybe it's a different issue all together. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check your `PATH`

Comment: Are you running java -version on command line? You also need to change the JAVA_HOME in User or System Environment variables.